# Does anyone else find the NativeScript GridLayout's 'row/column' and 'rows/cols' pair confusing?

Tags: nativescript, grid-layout

In my humble opinion, it should either be

`<GridLayout rows="auto auto" cols="auto auto"></GridLayout>`

and then:
`<Lable row="0" col="0"></Label>` etc.

or

`<GridLayout rows="auto auto" columns="auto auto"></GridLayout>`

and then:
`<Lable row="0" column="0"></Label>` etc.

It almost always gets me when I am not copying pasting, as to which one is using col and which one is using column..

**Did anyone else ever feel this inconsistency?**

Comment: If you want to give share your feedback or propose a change, [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues) may be the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Earlier it was confusing to me as well. Now I remember this by following the below technique

> Every cell needs a row(**singular** - **3** letter word) and to match that we need
>   a col(**singular** - **3** letter word), then for the top level you can use
>   columns.

:)

Comment: Well that does make sense, makes it easy to remember.. but would it be too much work for the NativeScript guys to simply add a wrapper for col and colum  in both rows and top level gridlayout tag?

Comment: Don't know what was their reasoning behind this but if you are using Angular, you can create your own `directive`